# how to get function name and structure details in gem5-21.2 when you run a program

Tags: linux, function, debugging, structure, gem5

when I run a program in gem5-21.2 on armv8 architecture, how can I get function name like A1_B1 and structure like A1_B1->C0 details through the debugflags.

I hope get a specific procedure through modifying the debugflag or other ways.

Comment: how can i ues symbol table to get these information